# Backup and restore IMAP mail account with (open source) Linux tools

Tags: email, backup, imap, restore

**Which Linux tools help to backup and restore a IMAP mail account including all mail and subfolders?**

I expect disconnects for large IMAP accounts because of

1. ressource limitiations on the server
2. risk of an interruption increases with the duration.

The software should be able to reconnect and continue the job after any interruption. For repeating backups it might be very handy to use incremental backups and to run the backup script in a cron job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 7 year old question, which I've searched for now, and there are a few answers, most of are spot on. But I feel at least one is missing, and there is probably room for more:

Timeline of answers:

- Back in 2014 [Mehmet mentioned imapsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174237/138012)

  This is probably still the most focused solution maintained out there, as this is an active stream of revenue for the author Gilles Lamiral. The source is available, currently the latest code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync)


  Although not available as a distro package (like some of the other options), it does have an official docker-hub hosted image at [gilleslamiral/imapsync](https://hub.docker.com/r/gilleslamiral/imapsync). For more info see: https://imapsync.lamiral.info/INSTALL.d/Dockerfile


  It seems someone also created a [docker-image](https://hub.docker.com/r/luskan777/imapsync-ui) for the WebUI.
- Back in 2017 [Quarind mentioned imap-backup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386764/138012)

  This is a ruby based solution, it looks like it's still being maintained.
- Back in 2021 [Patrick Decat mentioned OfflineIMAP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638728/138012)

  **offlineimap** is Python2 based and not really maintained.

  **offlineimap3** is a Python3 based fork that is [actively maintained](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap3)

  Available in [most distros](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=mailsync)

My research led me to these additional options:

- **isync** (the package name for the **`mbsync`** command)

  [Home page](https://isync.sourceforge.io/) | [Arch Wiki Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Isync) | [Distro/Package availability](https://pkgs.org/download/isync)

The packages below are available on Debian 11 (bullseye), but I don't know much about them yet:

- imapcopy

  Unmainted since ~[2009](http://www.ardiehl.de/imapcopy/)
- interimap

  Still actively maintained at [developer's website](https://www.guilhem.org/interimap/)
- mailsync

  On [SourceForge](http://mailsync.sourceforge.net/)
- mswatch

  [repo](http://mswatch.sourceforge.net/). Requires something to do the actual syncing.
- vdirsyncer

  [site](http://vdirsyncer.pimutils.org/en/stable/). Companion to other IMAP synchers, for syncing Calendar and Contacts.

### Update 2022-05

Specifically for Gmail / Google Workspace mailboxes<sup>*</sup>:
* Not an IMAP solution, but might be related to somebody's search, so I feel it's worth mentioning

- [Got Your Back](https://github.com/GAM-team/got-your-back/wiki#Introduction)
- [Gmvault](http://gmvault.org) <sub>[GitHub](https://github.com/gaubert/gmvault)</sub>

As I learn more I'll update this, as I'm actively looking for a solution myself.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use open source project imap-backup: https://github.com/joeyates/imap-backup

```
$ imap-backup setup
```

The setup system is a menu-driven command line application.

It creates ~/.imap-backup directory and configuration file. E.g.:

```
{
  "accounts":
  [
    {
      "username": "my.user@gmail.com",
      "password": "secret",
      "local_path": "/path/to/backup/root",
      "folders":
        [
          {"name": "[Gmail]/All Mail"},
          {"name": "my_folder"}
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It connects to GMail by default, but you can also specify a server:

```
{
  "accounts":
  [
    {
      "username": "my.user@gmail.com",
      "password": "secret",
      "server": "my.imap.example.com",
      "local_path": "/path/to/backup/root",
      "folders":
        [
          {"name": "[Gmail]/All Mail"},
          {"name": "my_folder"}
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: At least describe how how to use to tool and describe whether it accomodates the OP's expected hardships.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: This is by far the best tool I've met on my years long search for a solid imap backup tool!

Answer (score 4):

> OfflineIMAP is a GPLv2 software to dispose your mailbox(es) as a local Maildir(s).
>
> For example, this allows reading the mails while offline without the need for your mail reader (MUA) to support disconnected operations.
>
> OfflineIMAP will synchronize both sides via IMAP.

http://www.offlineimap.org/

https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap

It also supports restoring to an IMAP server: http://www.offlineimap.org/doc/backups-restore.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) for this. You can get the source from [fedorahosted.org imapsync](https://fedorahosted.org/imapsync/) page. [Zimbra Guide to imapsync](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Guide_to_imapsync) has good documentation about this subject.

Answer (score -1):

More to do with backing up than your questions but I've just found and started testing mailpiler. Not sure I like the fact of giving access to "all" email so working out how to send "older" email on regular basis to file there.

At the moment we use Awesome Auto Archive thunderbird extensions to "move" emails to another filing account.

Comment: `mailpiler` seems to be a commercial web service where you can send all your mails to. Besides obvious security concerns this is not what was asked for in this question.

Answer (score -4):

"cp -pr" should do the job. The "r" option in "pr" should take care of both subfolders and any hidden files/directories.

Comment: I guess this answer assumes the mails are in a Maildir type format in which case any tool to copy the files should work, and `rsync` might be a good option. But I think OP is interested in a solution that connects remotely through `IMAP`.